# Manipulating the Top Links in Magento

Tags: magento

This is just a quick question so I'll get straight to the point. Is there a way to change the top links without making any changes at the header.phtml file? I'm worried that it might break the entire website if I rely on the phtml file in changing the top link. Also, is there any guide I can use to use a static block to place top links instead? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See these files.If you are using theme other than default then check files accordingly there you can change the link names.

1. app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/checkout.xml
2. `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/customer.xml`

Find there  `<reference name="top.links">`

There you can change the top links.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. So just so we're clear? Either way I have to change something in the files?

Comment: Also, what if I'm making a multilingual store? How can I switch the English text to another language if that's how I'm going to make the top links?